# is it okay in a journal to express the vector-scalar division like this

Tags: notation

Assume you want to show that a vector is divided by a scalar and then the norm is taken, i.e.

$\|\frac{x}{c}\|$

where x is the vector, and c is the scalar.

So is it okay to show it like this? I don't want to take "c" out of the norm.

Comment: That seems OK, you could also write $\|\frac{1}{c}x\|$ if you really want to be certain not to confuse.

Comment: Of course that is ok (as long as $c \neq 0$). I see notation like that all the time (and use it myself).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience!